# How to pass a code snippet from mdx file to react component?

Tags: reactjs, storybook, pre

I am writing up documentation for a storybook application I am working on. I am wondering how I would set code snippet for the content. For example:

```tsx
// ExampleComponent.tsx
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react'

interface ExampleComponentProps {
  children: ReactElement
}

const ExampleComponent = ({ children }: ExampleComponentProps): ReactElement => (
  <div>{children}</div>
)
```

````mdx
// ExampleStory.mdx
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'
import ExampleComponent from './ExampleComponent.tsx'

<Meta title="Example/Overview" />

```tsx 
This works```

<pre className="language-tsx">
  {`return (
    <div>this works, without the styling</div>
  )`}
</pre>

<ExampleComponent>
  <pre className="language-tsx">
    {`return (
      <div>this works the same as above, without the styling</div>
    )`}
   </pre>
</ExampleComponent>
````

I've tried using the MDXProvider, but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) or [prism](https://prismjs.com/) to achieve this. They are easy to use.

Comment: I tried using prism since that seems what storybook is using, but I was having a lot of issues getting their styling.